# redirect from action inside controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC - instead of creating a VM and passing in the values and drawing the view. i want to redirect to a URL using the values as parameters....so

instead of:

```
var model = new AvailabilityStepOneOfBookingVM(bookingQuery, 
                     ListOfBookings, chosenDate, foodPodId);

return View(model);
```

I want to load the URL:

```
http://localhost:40310/OrchardLocal/Food/FoodPodAvailability/
          StepOneOfBooking/(value of foodPodId)/(value of chosenDate)
```

redirect to action? directly from here or create a view and redirect from there?

Comment: Is there a route setup for that destination url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Redirect`

```
string url = string.Format("/OrchardLocal/Food/FoodPodAvailability" + 
                           "/StepOneOfBooking/{1}/{0}", chosenDate, foodPodId)

return Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 string url = string.Format("/OrchardLocal/Food/FoodPodAvailability" + 
                       "/StepOneOfBooking/{1}/{0}", chosenDate, foodPodId)


 return RedirectToAction(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have configurated your routes, you can do like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { foodPodId = 1,chosenDate = "2013-09-11" });
```